# antd components are hidden later than the parent div

Tags: reactjs, components, antd

I have a box which makes itself visible when a button is clicked. The box has a text field and a button. When that button is clicked, the box must hide again. But my problem is the box hides first and for a split second, i still can see the antd components.

```
box = () => {
  <div style={{visibility: this.state.visibility}}>
    <Input type= 'text' />
    <Button onClick={() => {this.hideBox()}}>Send</Button>
  </div>
}
showBox = () => {
  this.setState({visibility: 'visible'});
}
hideBox = () => {
  this.setState({visibility: 'hidden'});
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => {this.showBox()}}>Show</Button>
      {this.box()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know how to make them hide at the same time.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
style={{display: `${this.state.visibility ? 'block' : 'none'}`}}
```

Answer (score 0):

because antd components has it's default style: `transition:"all 0.3s"`.
[styles in devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmmmt.png)

if you hide it with style, I suggest using `dispaly:block/none`,instead of `visibility`.